# dplyr behaviour within case_when and lag

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I have a dataset which has studyid, year, and two flags: incident and prevalent.
I wish the prevalent variable to be TRUE (1) for all years after the incident flag is true (and the incident variable can be true only once).  case_when and lag seem the perfect combination, but if incident is set to 1 in year N, prevalent is set to TRUE only in N+1, and reverse to 0 in N+1. This was not the expected behaviour.

Here is sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)

# make a fake dataset
testdat <- tribble(
  ~studyid, ~datestring, ~incident,
  "1", "2000-01-01", 0,
  "1", "2001-01-01", 1,
  "1", "2002-01-01", 0,
  "1", "2003-01-01", 0,
  "2", "2003-01-01", 0,
  "2", "2004-01-01", 1,
  "2", "2005-01-01", 0,
  "2", "2006-01-01", 0
) %>% mutate(
  prevalent = 0,
  date = lubridate::ymd(datestring)
) %>% group_by(studyid) %>% 
  arrange(studyid, date) %>% 
  mutate(prevalent = case_when(
    #logic is, if prevalent in year N-1, the prevalent in year N
    # if incident in year N-1, then prevalent in year N
    # otherwise not prevalent (because never incident)
    dplyr::lag(prevalent, 1L)==1 ~1,
    dplyr::lag(incident, 1L)==1 ~1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  ) #close case_when
  ) #close mutate
testdat
```

Output is:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   studyid [2]
  studyid datestring incident prevalent date      
  <chr>   <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl> <date>    
1 1       2000-01-01        0         0 2000-01-01
2 1       2001-01-01        1         0 2001-01-01
3 1       2002-01-01        0         1 2002-01-01
4 1       2003-01-01        0         0 2003-01-01
5 2       2003-01-01        0         0 2003-01-01
6 2       2004-01-01        1         0 2004-01-01
7 2       2005-01-01        0         1 2005-01-01
8 2       2006-01-01        0         0 2006-01-01
>
```

Desired output is:

```
studyid=1, year=2003  prevalent ==1 (not 0)
studyid=2, year=2006  prevalent ==1 (not 0)
```

I suspect this has to do with how case_when is interacting with dplyr::lag.
How can I improve the logic/syntax to obtain the needed results?

Many thanks,

Comment: Test with an ifelse (with an OR condition) instead of a case when.

Comment: @user2292410 Its doing what you desired. check the logic: do you want to check prevalent/ incident in any of the n-1 years ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like the last observation carried forward e.g `zoo::na.locf` or `tidyr::fill`, but I'll use something simple like:

```
library(dplyr)
testdat %>% 
   mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(datestring)) %>% group_by(studyid) %>% 
   arrange(studyid, date) %>% mutate(prevalent=cumsum(lag(incident,default = 0)==1))

# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   studyid [2]
  studyid datestring incident date       prevalent
  <chr>   <chr>         <dbl> <date>         <int>
1 1       2000-01-01        0 2000-01-01         0
2 1       2001-01-01        1 2001-01-01         0
3 1       2002-01-01        0 2002-01-01         1
4 1       2003-01-01        0 2003-01-01         1
5 2       2003-01-01        0 2003-01-01         0
6 2       2004-01-01        1 2004-01-01         0
7 2       2005-01-01        0 2005-01-01         1
8 2       2006-01-01        0 2006-01-01         1
```

Comment: Most helpful, and not "simple". Never thought to use cumsum in this way. Many thanks!