# count onwards with dplyr and lag() in mutate()

Tags: if-statement, dplyr, lag, counting, mutate

I have a data frame with several rows per group.
As a result of a package which adds some variables I have a dataframe in long format where each group has different number of rows.
I want to repeat the last column per group to have the same number of rows per group ("nrow" specifies the group).
Than I want to continue counting one variable here called "Tstart".

I was looking for other posts with related questions ([Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53998684/dplyr-behaviour-within-case-when-and-lag)), but couldn't figure this problem out alone.

This is an example data frame

```
test <- tibble(
  nrow = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
  Tstart = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
  other = c(letters[1:9])
)

> test
# A tibble: 9 × 3
   nrow Tstart other
  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>
1     1      1 a    
2     1      2 b    
3     2      1 c    
4     2      2 d    
5     2      3 e    
6     3      1 f    
7     3      2 g    
8     3      3 h    
9     3      4 i    
>
```

I repeat each last row so each group has the same number of rows

```
test2 <- test %>% 
  group_by(nrow)%>%
  arrange(Tstart) %>%
  mutate(last_Tstart = max(Tstart))%>%
  slice(c(1:n(), rep(n(), 4-n()) ))%>%
  ungroup()

> test2
# A tibble: 12 × 4
    nrow Tstart other last_Tstart
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
 1     1      1 a               2
 2     1      2 b               2
 3     1      2 b               2
 4     1      2 b               2
 5     2      1 c               3
 6     2      2 d               3
 7     2      3 e               3
 8     2      3 e               3
 9     3      1 f               4
10     3      2 g               4
11     3      3 h               4
12     3      4 i               4
```

Now I want to count onwards the Tstart column. I tried the following:

```
test2 %>%
  group_by(nrow)%>%
  mutate(Tstart = if_else(
    Tstart == last_Tstart  , dplyr::lag(Tstart) + 1,
    Tstart))
```

but it results in

```
    nrow Tstart other last_Tstart
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
 1     1      1 a               2
 2     1      2 b               2
 3     1      3 b               2
 4     1      3 b               2
 5     2      1 c               3
 6     2      2 d               3
 7     2      3 e               3
 8     2      4 e               3
 9     3      1 f               4
10     3      2 g               4
11     3      3 h               4
12     3      4 i               4
```

Row 4 should have in Tstart a 4 instead of a 3.

Thank you a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want `row_number()`

```
test2 %>% group_by(nrow) %>%  mutate(Tstart=row_number())
```

Output:

```
    nrow Tstart other last_Tstart
   <dbl>  <int> <chr>       <dbl>
 1     1      1 a               2
 2     1      2 b               2
 3     1      3 b               2
 4     1      4 b               2
 5     2      1 c               3
 6     2      2 d               3
 7     2      3 e               3
 8     2      4 e               3
 9     3      1 f               4
10     3      2 g               4
11     3      3 h               4
12     3      4 i               4
```

If `Tstart` doesn't always start with `1`, you can use something like this:

```
test2 %>% group_by(nrow) %>%  mutate(Tstart = row_number() + min(Tstart)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @langtang way solved my question as I phrased it, so I accepted it. Thank you very much.
I figured out a more flexible and intuitive way, where rows to add for Tstart can be specified which don't need to but can be consecutive.

```
 test <- tibble(
  nrow = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
  Tstart = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
  other = c(letters[1:9])
)

# create dataframe with Tstart values you need.
times <- c(1,3,5)
testtimes <- data.frame(
      nrow = rep(unique(test$nrow), each = length(times)), 
      Tstart_new = rep(times, by = length(unique(test$nrow))))
# join it to the existing data frame
full_join(test, testtimes,
          by = c("nrow" = "nrow", "Tstart" = "Tstart_new")) %>%
  arrange(nrow, Tstart) %>% 
# carry forward the values for other columns
  fill(everything())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 13 × 3
    nrow Tstart other
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>
 1     1      1 a    
 2     1      2 b    
 3     1      3 b    
 4     1      5 b    
 5     2      1 c    
 6     2      2 d    
 7     2      3 e    
 8     2      5 e    
 9     3      1 f    
10     3      2 g    
11     3      3 h    
12     3      4 i    
13     3      5 i
```